# C++ project to linux

Tags: c++, mysql, linux

I have a C++ project build on Visual C++ Express 2010 which includes a mysql dynamic library. I would to to convert it to a linux executable file. How may I achieve that?

Comment: This is overly broad. First of all is the project using Windows-specific APIs ? MySQL libraries are usually portable so this should not be an issue. Also do you know any build system that works in Linux ? (CMake, or simple Makefiles...) I'm assuming you want to compile your code in Linux, and not just need a compiled Windows executable to run on Linux, in which case Wine or other virtualisation software might be solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"How may I achieve that?"*

That totally depends on how portably your C++ code was written. If you only have dependencies to the [MySQL C++ API](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index.html), then chances are good, that you can [install the necessary libraries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-installation-source.html) on your linux system, and build your executable linking against these.

Comment: Exactly. Portable code is portable, but anything binding against the Windows API is going to be nothing but headaches.

Comment: I think I have some idea now. Thank you.